# java threads or swingWorker and gui good practice

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface

I had a little issue, I wanted to do something in a thread and after it finishes to open a new GUI window. I found a couple of solutions:

1. Is to make a thread and inside the thread do my work and line after that update my GUI, to me this way feels not good, because I feel that updating my GUI through a thread who wasn't meant for updating GUI isn't the best idea.

   ```
   new Thread(() -> {
       doSomethingsHere()
       updateGui();
   }).start();
   ```
2. Using a SwingWorker which was built exactly for this, however takes a lot of lines and doing it couple of times might make my code a bit messy.

   ```
   public void doThingsInBackground() {
       SwingWorker<Void,Void> SwingWorker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>(){
           protected Void doInBackground(){
               doSomethingsHere()
               return (Void) new Object();
           }

           protected void done(){
               updateGui();
           }
       };
       SwingWorker.execute();
   }
   ```
3. Using a thread and a listener, like a custom event that when the thread ends the event runs, which for some reason feels the best for me.

My question is, which is the best "good practice"?

Answer (score 0):

`SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable);` or `SwingWorker` is the way to go. Updating UI from `Thread` will not work, as UI events need to be processed in EDT (event dispatch thread) - main thread.

`SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable);` dispatches runnable to EDT to be processed. SwingWorker is doing the same when `process(List)` or `done()` are invoked.

Comment: weird because the first method worked for me as well.
anyway thanks, great explanation.